# Show searchbar and focus it after keypress

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to show a searchbar when the user presses the "R" key, the searchbar should also be focused after the key press, here's the fiddle:

```js
buttonKeyAllowed = true;

function disparitionMenu() 
/* this function is used to show the searchbar */
{
    var input = jQuery("#mod-search-searchword");
    input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = input.val().length;
    jQuery("#menu-search").css("display", "inline-block");
}
    
/*-- key events --*/


jQuery(document).keyup(function() {
  buttonKeyAllowed = true;
});


jQuery(document).focus(function(e) { 
  buttonKeyAllowed = true;
});


jQuery(document).keypress(function(e) {  
       
  if (e.repeat != undefined) {
    buttonKeyAllowed = !e.repeat;
  }
  if (!buttonKeyAllowed) 
    return;
  buttonKeyAllowed = false;


  var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);

  if(code == 114) {
    disparitionMenu();
  }
});
```

```css
#menu-search
{
  display: none;
}

input{
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


  <div id="megamenu">
    <div id="menu-search">
      <input type="text" id="mod-search-searchword" />
    </div>
  </div>
```

This code works nice, but there's one problem:

When the user presses the "R" key a little bit too long, 'r' is written in the searchbar, and I want to avoid it.

What's the cleanest way to correct this problem? I don't want to add a `while(/* is R key down*/){}` loop before the function `disparitionMenu()`

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `input.focus();` to your `function disparitionMenu()`. Check below code.

```js
buttonKeyAllowed = true;

var isVisible = false;

function disparitionMenu()
  /* this function is used to show the searchbar */
  {
    var input = jQuery("#mod-search-searchword");
    input[0].selectionStart = input[0].selectionEnd = input.val().length;
    jQuery("#menu-search").css("display", "inline-block");
    input.focus();
  }

/*-- key events --*/


jQuery(document).keyup(function() {
  buttonKeyAllowed = true;
});

jQuery(document).focus(function(e) {
  buttonKeyAllowed = true;
});

jQuery(document).keypress(function(e) {

  if (e.repeat != undefined) {
    buttonKeyAllowed = !e.repeat;
  }
  if (!buttonKeyAllowed)
    return;
  buttonKeyAllowed = false;


  var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);

  if (code == 114) {
    if (!isVisible) {
      isVisible = true;
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    disparitionMenu();
  }
});
```

```css
#menu-search {
  display: none;
}
input {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="megamenu">
  <div id="menu-search">
    <input type="text" id="mod-search-searchword" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I wanted :)

Answer (score 2):

Put your input with readonly

```
<input type="text" id="mod-search-searchword" readonly="true" />
```

on event onkeyup if is r put readonly false or remove it.

```
jQuery(document).keyup(function(e) {        
    var code = (e.keyCode || e.which);    
  if(code == 82) {
    $('#mod-search-searchword').removeAttr('readonly');
  }
});
```

also remove the event :) ^

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution works too, but I prefer Pugazh's solution.